# In a big Java project can not locate .java file belonging to a package using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, path

I'm new to java with a C++ background. I'm using Eclipse and have imported projects created by maven using "mvn eclipse:eclipse". In eclipse, when I highlight a class name from another class and do "Open Declaration", eclipse would normally open the corresponding .java file.

However, for one of the classes, eclipse "Open Declaration" opens up a .class file which shows all the context of the file. However, this file is not editable. Furthermore, I can't locate the actual .java file behind it. There is a package line in the beginning of the .class file and it points to a directory that doesn't seem exist. I believe there is a way to trace back to the original .java file from the .class file but I'm not sure how to do this. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

The class is likely in one of your dependency jars, so you don't have the source locally in a project.  Many maven published projects allow for the source to be downloaded in a jar, and eclipse can use that to display the source, but editing it would be meaningless in that instance.

If you hit ctrl+shift+T and search for the class you should be able to see the location of the class in the bottom portion of the "open type" dialog.

In the eclipse "properties" for the jar that contains the class, you should be able to set the "Java Source Attachment" to the folder on your system that contains the source (if you have it)

Comment: +1 and as a likely fix: do `mvn eclipse:eclipse -DdownLoadSources`, that will attach the sources if available.

Comment: Digitaljoel, I followed your paragraphs 1 and 2 and not sure what #3 is. Please elaborate. Thank you.

Comment: your best bet would be to use Sean Patrick Floyd's advice instead of my third paragraph.  My third paragraph is the manual, difficult way to attach source to a jar resource in your project, his is the automatic way.